# How to store value in session using a combination of PHP and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

I made a search filter using radio buttons and I wanted to store the value from the radio button to a session. The value that will be stored in the session will be used to make the radio buttons stay checked even after reload.

```
`<script>
    function handleRadio(elm)
    {
    window.location="equipment.php?section=";

     <?php
     $_SESSION['state']="";?>+elm.value;
      }
     </script>

      <form action="" method="POST">
      <?php
      $state=$_SESSION['state'];
             ?>
<input type="radio" name="state" value="allstate" onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='allstate' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> All State <br>

<input type="radio" name="state" value="new" onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='new' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> New EQ: <br>

<input type="radio" name="state" value="old" onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='old' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Old EQ: <br>

<input type="radio" name="state" value="unknown" onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='unknown' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Unknown State: <br>
             </form>  `
```

The function hadleRadio() gets the value from the radio button and passes it to a session. The session will be stored later in a php variable. However, I cant think of any solution to combine PHP and Javascript to store the value from the radio as the current  has syntax errors.

Comment: we can not append js data to php data as they are render at different time(php-server side, js-client sire).

Comment: You will have to use ajax to set the session in PHP, passing elm.value in the ajax request .